# submit form from iframe and close it after submit and show a hidden div

Tags: javascript, forms, iframe, hide, show

this is what I have

```
    <html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    <iframe id="myiframe">
    <form id= "myform" action="submit.php" method="POST">
    <input type="submit">
    </form></iframe>
    <div id="hiddendiv" style="display:none">
    some text
    </div>
    </body></html>
```

and this is what I want to end up with after the form in the iframe is submitted (ether by enter or just clicking the button submit, I do not care because the form only has 1 field)

```
    <html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    //I want this iframe to become display:none or to be deleted
    /*<iframe id="myiframe">
    <form id= "myform" action="submit.php" method="POST">
    <input type="submit">
    </form></iframe>*/
    //and this div to be showed
    <div id="hiddendiv" style="display:">
    some text
    </div>
    </body></html>
```

can anyone please help, thanks

i have the answare but I have to wait for 8 h to post is so I edited the initial question, you can pot is if you want so I can validate it as a answare

got it

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<script>

function closeIframe() {
var iframe = document.getElementById('myiframe');
iframe.parentNode.removeChild(iframe);
document.getElementById("hiddendiv").style.display="";
}

</script>
<iframe id="myiframe">
<form id= "myform" action="submit.php" method="POST">
<input type="submit">
</form></iframe>
<div id="hiddendiv" style="display:none">
some text
</div>
</body></html>
```

and in the submit.php the return is this

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
echo 'parent.closeIframe()';
echo '</script>';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<script>

function closeIframe() {
var iframe = document.getElementById('myiframe');
iframe.parentNode.removeChild(iframe);
document.getElementById("hiddendiv").style.display="";
}

</script>
<iframe id="myiframe">
<form id= "myform" action="submit.php" method="POST">
<input type="submit">
</form></iframe>
<div id="hiddendiv" style="display:none">
some text
</div>
</body></html>
```

and in the submit.php the return is this

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
echo 'parent.closeIframe()';
echo '</script>';
```

Answer (score 1):

If from same domain, add this in the submit.php and extract the form to put in the iframe
You need

```
<iframe src="form.html"></iframe>
```

[DEMO](http://plungjan.name/SO/iframe1.html)

```
<script>
top.document.getElementById("myiframe").style.display="none";        
top.document.getElementById("hiddendiv").style.display="block";
</script>
```

Comment: :) I know you know what your saying but I do not know how to implement that

Comment: so the submit.php is a mailer in my situation. so I can put something like if the email is sent return ..... how do I formulate the code in php?

Comment: does not display the hiddendive and in firebug it shows me that the iframe still eats the space where it is, like when you hide it, so can I delete the iframe?

Comment: I had a typo. Use `document.` instead of `document,` - see update

Comment: thanks but I have the solution, check my question, please copy paste it so I can validate it as a solution